# How to store and return a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, binary, return, hex

My code (below) takes a text file with hexadecimal values and converts the hexadecimal value to binary and **prints** it. How can I modify this so that my hex_to_binary function can initialise a string array and add the converted binary to the array and then **return** the array. Then I just want to print the output of the hex_to_binary function by adding a printf statement in my main function. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>

int hex_to_binary(char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char line[100];

    while(!feof(file)){
        fgets(line,100,file);
        hex_to_binary(line);
    }
    fclose(file);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int hex_to_binary(char* hex_string)
{
    int i=0;
    printf("\nEquivalent binary value: ");
    while(hex_string[i])
    {
         switch(hex_string[i])
         {
             case '0': printf("0000"); break;
             case '1': printf("0001"); break;
             case '2': printf("0010"); break;
             case '3': printf("0011"); break;
             case '4': printf("0100"); break;
             case '5': printf("0101"); break;
             case '6': printf("0110"); break;
             case '7': printf("0111"); break;
             case '8': printf("1000"); break;
             case '9': printf("1001"); break;
             case 'A': printf("1010"); break;
             case 'B': printf("1011"); break;
             case 'C': printf("1100"); break;
             case 'D': printf("1101"); break;
             case 'E': printf("1110"); break;
             case 'F': printf("1111"); break;
             case 'a': printf("1010"); break;
             case 'b': printf("1011"); break;
             case 'c': printf("1100"); break;
             case 'd': printf("1101"); break;
             case 'e': printf("1110"); break;
             case 'f': printf("1111"); break;
        }
        i++;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't return arrays in the C programming language. You could return a pointer to memory obtained via `malloc()` or similar function if that's what you want.

Comment: How would I implement that in my code? sorry I come from Python background

Answer (score 0):

strcat() function is what you want.

if I were you, for simplicity I do this one below :

Define Global Char array :

```
char buffer[1000]; // define a space to write our string

....
```

Change your hex function like this :

```
while(hex_string[i])
        {
             switch(hex_string[i])
             {
                 case '0': strcat(buffer,"0000"); break;
                 case '1': strcat(buffer,"0001"); break;
                 case '2': strcat(buffer,"0010"); break;
                 ....
             }
        }
```

In main use this to print your string :

```
 printf("%s\n",buffer);
```

Note: Don't forget to clear buffer after your each hex_to_binary function call (otherwise it keeps the previous numbers inside)

Comment: I'm getting error: Use of undeclared identifier 'buffer' - when I I insert that printf statement in main. And also how would you clear the buffer?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

The one thing you *can't* do is declare a character array in the function, use sprintf to print to it, and return it.  You cannot be certain that the space it points to exists anymore after the function returns.

That is, *DON'T* do this:

```
int hex_to_binary(char *hex_string)
{
    char binary_string[MAX_SIZE + 1];

    <...>

    return binary_string;
}
```

To do exactly what you state, you can call malloc to obtain the space inside the function, then return a pointer to it:

```
int hex_to_binary(char *hex_string)
{
    char *binary_string;

    if((binary_string = malloc(MAX_SIZE + 1)) == NULL)
        return -1;   /* Indicate failure */
    binary_string[0] = '\0';

    <etc>

        switch(hex_string[i])
        {
            case '0' : strcat(binary_string, "0000"); break;

    <etc>

    return binary_string;
}
```

This is permitted, because malloc is allocating the memory, probably in the heap, and this memory will still exist afterwards.  The issue is, the function that calls hex_to_binary needs to call free() to release this memory, otherwise every call steals a little bit of memory -- this is known as a memory leak.

That is, do:

```
char *binary_line;

while(!feof(file)){
    fgets(line,100,file);
    binary_line = hex_to_binary(line);
    printf("%s", binary_line);
    free(binary_line);
}
```

*NOT*

```
while(!feof(file)){
    fgets(line,100,file);
    printf("%s", hex_to_binary(line););
}
```

If you were to call the hex_to_binary in a loop, once per hex digit, you could change the case statements to return a pointer to a string, instead of printing:

```
switch(hex_digit)
{
    case '0' : return "0000";
    case '2' : return "0001"; 

    <etc>
```

This returns a pointer to constant string that you could print and saves freeing the space afterwards.

Another option would be to pass hex_to_binary two parameters, one with the string to convert, and one a pointer to the space to write it to:

```
int hex_to_binary(char *hex_string, char *binary_line)
{
    <etc>

        switch(hex_string[i])
        {
            case '0' : strcat(binary_string, "0000"); break;

    <etc>

    return 0;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
char binary_line[MAX_SPACE + 1];

while(!feof(file)){
    fgets(line,100,file);
    hex_to_binary(line, binary_line);
    printf("%s", binary_line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change to like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *hexstr_to_binstr(char *outbuff, const char *s);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char line[100];
    char binstr[4*sizeof(line)];

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)){
        puts(hexstr_to_binstr(binstr, line));
    }
    fclose(file);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

const char *xdigit_to_binstr(char x){
    switch(x){
        case '0': return("0000");
        case '1': return("0001");
        case '2': return("0010");
        case '3': return("0011");
        case '4': return("0100");
        case '5': return("0101");
        case '6': return("0110");
        case '7': return("0111");
        case '8': return("1000");
        case '9': return("1001");
        case 'a': 
        case 'A': return("1010");
        case 'b': 
        case 'B': return("1011");
        case 'c': 
        case 'C': return("1100");
        case 'd': 
        case 'D': return("1101");
        case 'e': 
        case 'E': return("1110");
        case 'f': 
        case 'F': return("1111");
        default : return "";
    }
    return NULL;//never reach this point
}
char *hexstr_to_binstr(char *outbuff, const char *s){
    char *p = outbuff;

    for(; *s ; ++s){
        if(isxdigit(*s)){
            memcpy(p, xdigit_to_binstr(*s), 4);
            p += 4;
        }
    }
    *p = 0;
    return outbuff;
}
```